# Changing Cookie header value at every request in Django

Tags: django, django-middleware

Somehow the values for in the Cookie change at every request.

As I'm using the auth and session middleware (which add the Vary: Cookie header). I'm not able to cache the pages.

Any hints how I can change this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have this behaviour on all kinds of browsers.

The session.backend is the standard one (I dont have anything set in my settings.py file).

Comment: To be more specific:

This is the cookie that is constantly changing:
__utmb   241116550.3.10.1250168027

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this has nothing todo with django.

The changing cookie values were caused by the google analytics tracker.

This made the standard chache_site mechanism impossible.

Answer (score 1):

As @msmart found, this is an annoying effect of Google Analytics and a bit of a problem with the vary-on-cookie pattern (you can't specify which cookies you want to vary on)

There is a bug for Django here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9249
which has a patch for Django.

This will let you get your Django-side caching behaviour working again, but http proxy caches will still fail to cache pages due to the changing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

what are you using for the session backend?

see: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine

whoops...should have been a comment...not an answer...